# Saving Tkinter Canvas object

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I save a Canvas object so I can modify it later (delete drawings, add drawings, etc)?

I tried pickle but it gave me an error: `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'tkapp' object: <tkapp object at 0x024A7678>`

```
canvas = Canvas()

canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 80, 80, outline="red", fill="green", width=10)

file_name = "test_file"

with open(file_name, 'wb') as file_object:
    pickle.dump(canvas, file_object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more direct solution, but I usually deal with this by saving the objects that indicate the drawing, and passing them a new canvas at each session. This typically fits into a well designed infrastructure anyway - it separates the image from the data.

For example, you might be tracking ovals separately anyways, like the following:

```
class Oval:

    def __init__( self, x , y ):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y

   def draw_to_canvas(self,canvas):
       canvas.create_oval( ..., ... )

newoval = Oval(0,0)
pickle.dump(newoval,myfile)
```

I'm not sure how often you need to pickle the actual tkinter canvas - making a new one of those is pretty easy. What you want is a saved version of the objects on the canvas, which you can obtain by pickling the custom classes you make to track the data. Tkinter is generally not robust enough, in my opinion, to act as a data structure and a canvas, nor does it seem like a very elegant design to have it act as both.

Of course, it may be more efficient to pickle a list of ovals, or a hierarchical tree-like container if you're trying to make a drawing engine. It's all usage specific